# How -128 fits in a sbyte

Tags: c#, types, sbyte

As I remember we had learned that signed integer types (sbyte, short, int , long)
the first bit is for the sign and the latter 7 bit is for the value.

I saw that sbyte range is -128 to 127 while I thought it must be -127 to 127.

I tried some codes to understand how this is possible and I faced two strange things:

1- I tried the following code:

```
sbyte a = -128;
Console.Write(Convert.ToString(a, 2));
```

and the resutl was

> 1111111100000000

As if its a two byte variable.

2-Tried converting all numbers in the range to binary:

```
for(sbyte i=-128;i<=127;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(i, 2));
    if(i==127) break;
}
```

If I omit the `if(i==127) break;` the loop goes on. and with the break, the code in the loop does not execute, some how as if -128 is greater than 127.

**My Conclusion:**
As I thought that -128 must not fit in a unsigned byte variable and the first and second tries approves that (111111110000000 > 01111111)
but If it does not fit, then why range is -128 to 127?

Comment: I couldn't find a suitable title for the post

Comment: The signed integer types are not "sign-magnitude" types. They use "2's compliment" representation, which has the range -128 to 127 for a sign byte. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Comment: You've miscounted the number of ones and zeros in your "16-bit result".  The real value has 9 ones, 7 zeros, but in your question you typed 8 ones 8 zeros.

Comment: @Aziz Thanks a lot. this was really interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I saw that `sbyte` range is `-128` to `127` while I thought it must be `-127` to `127`.

The range is `[-128, +127]` indeed. The range `[-127, +127]` would mean that `sbyte` can represent only `255` different values, while 8 bits make `256` combinations.

And BTW if `-128` would not be a legal value, compiler would complain about

```
sbyte a = -128;
```

There is no overload `Convert.ToString(sbyte value, int toBase)`, so in your case `Convert.ToString(int value, int toBase)` is called, and `sbyte` is promoted to `int`.

To quickly check the value, you can print `sbyte` as a hexadecimal number:

```
sbyte s = -1;
Console.WriteLine("{0:X}", s); // FF, i.e. 11111111
```

> If I omit the `if(i==127) break;` the loop goes on.

Sure, `sbyte.MaxValue` is `127`, so `i<=127` is always `true`. When `i` is `127` and gets incremented, an overflow occurs and the next value is `-128`.

Comment: I know that -128 is a legal value, I wondered what its binary value would be. and Aziz's link explains it

Comment: Your code solves my other problem of getting strange value of `111111110000000`

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani You could just print as hex, I updated the post.